# How to set a check on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to add table called `group` with a column called `code`

How do I add a check constraint to the column so it will only allow the following  alphabetic characters (D, M, O, P or T) followed by 2 numeric characters.

Comment: Where are the alphabetic characters coming from?  Where are the numeric characters coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simple check constraint is all you need

```
create table blatest(code char(3))

alter table blatest add  constraint ck_bla 
check (code like '[DMOPT][0-9][0-9]' )
GO
```

test

```
insert blatest values('a12') --fails
insert blatest values('M12')  --good
insert blatest values('D12') --good
insert blatest values('DA1') --fails
```

If you need it to be case sensitive then you have to create the constraint like this

```
alter table blatest add  constraint ck_bla 
check (code like '[DMOPT][0-9][0-9]' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS )
GO
```

D12 will succeed but d12 will not in that case